# copy folder data from source location to destination locaton using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark, my task is to copy the source folder data to destination folder using pyspark where parallelization also happen.
in python  i can copy the data using

```
from shutil import copytree
copytree(source, destination)
```

with this i am able to recusively copy whole data with folder structure using standard python. i want to do the same. task using pyspark on a cluster. how should i proceed , i am using YARN as resource manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spark allows you to manipulate data, not files.
Therefore, I can offer you 2 solutions :

1 - You read your data with spark and write them where you need to :

```
spark.read.format(
    "my_format"
).load(
    "in_path"
).write.format(
    "my_format"
).save("out_path")
```

2 - the other solution is to use the hadoop tools :

```
from subprocess import call
call(["hdfs", "dfs", "-mv", "origine_path", "target_path"])
```

Comment: thanks . i like the second solution using hadoop tools ( as i have no need to worry about the file format ). i am copying the data in same volume cluster and have to read it from there . i am looking on other ways to do so also . currently i am working with the unix file system , using hard link and soft links . it will save space and data copy time.if you can help me on this , will appreciate . thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can load and write as a Dataframe (example for parquet):

```
df = spark.read.parquet(<your_input_path>)
df.write.parquet(<your_destination_path>)
```

Where 'your_input_path' can be a folder and it will copy all files in it